# creating a loop for invalid characters

Tags: c++

What I am trying to do is create a loop for invalid char so for example:
If the allowed characters are 'A','a','C','c' and the user inputs 'f'
it will say its invalid and ask them to input a new character until they enter a valid character.

I'm also not sure where it would go inside the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (){
    int units;
    double priceA,priceB,priceC;
    char package, goAgain;
    priceA=15.95;
    priceB=23.95;
    priceC=45.95;

    do {
        cout << "Enter the Package chosen. Enter 'A' or 'a' for package A.n";
        cout << "Enter 'b' or 'B' for package B.n";
        cout << "Enter 'c' or 'C' for package C.n";
        cin >> package;
        cout << "Enter the number of message units";
        cin >> units;

        while(units>672){
            cout <<endl;
            cout <<"Invalid number,please enter a value from 0 to 672."<<endl;
            cout <<"Please Enter a new Number for units.";
            cin >>units;
        }

        switch (package){
            case 'A':
            case 'a':
            if(units>10){
                priceA=15.95+(units-10)*.20;
                priceB=23.95+(units-20)*.10;

                cout <<"The price of Package A is" << " $"<<priceA<< endl;
            }
            else if(units<=10){
                priceA=15.95;
                cout << "The price of Package A is" << " $"<<priceA<<endl;

            }
            if (priceA>priceB){
                cout <<"By switching to Package B you would save" << " $" << priceA-        priceB<<endl;
            }
            if (priceA>priceC){
                cout << "By switching to Package C you would save" << " $"<<priceA-             priceC<<endl;
            }
            break;
            case 'b':
            case 'B':
            if(units>10){
                priceA=15.95+(units-10)*.20;
                priceB=23.95+(units-20)*.10;

                cout <<"The price of Package B is" << " $"<<priceB<< endl;
            }
            else if(units<=10){
                priceB=23.95;
                cout << "The price of Package B is" << " $"<<priceB<<endl;
            }
            if (priceB>priceA){
                cout <<"By switching to Package A you would save" << " $" << priceB-    priceA<<endl;
            }
            if (priceB>priceC){
                cout << "By switching to Package C you would save" << " $"<<priceB-priceC<<endl;
            }
            break;
            case 'c':
            case 'C':
            if(units>10){
                priceA=15.95+(units-10)*.20;
                priceB=23.95+(units-20)*.10;

                cout <<"The price of Package C is" << " $"<<priceC<< endl;
            }
            else if(units<=10){
                priceC=45.95;
                cout << "The price of Package C is" << " $"<<priceC<<endl;
            }
            if (priceC>priceA){
                cout <<"By switching to Package A you would save" << " $" << priceC-priceA<<endl;
            }
            if (priceC>priceB){
                cout << "By switching to Package B you would save" << " $"<<priceC-priceB<<endl;
            }
            break;
        }

        cout<<"do you want to go again? y/n" << endl;
        cin >>goAgain;
    }
    while(goAgain=='y');
}
```

Comment: If you're going to dump a big block of code in your question, at least indent it properly.

Comment: I fixed the indents, sorry if it is not the best.

Answer (score 0):

A switch can have a `default` branch which handles everything not handled in other `case` branches. You can put your code there and then put the whole `switch` in a `do` - `while` loop like this:

```
bool valid;
do {
    valid = true;

    switch (package) {
    case 'A':
        ⋮
    default:
        valid = false;
        cout << "Invalid bla bla " << package << ", enter it again" << endl;
        cin >> package;
        break;
    }
} while (!valid);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
bool valid = false;
while (!valid)
{
  const std::string valid_packages = "AaCc";
  char package;
  cin >> package;
  if (valid_packages.find(package) != std::string::npos)
  {
    valid = true;
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "\n"
         << "Invalid package name, try again.\n";
  }
}
```

The valid package letters are placed into a string.  The User's input is checked against the string of valid letters.  If the User's input is found, the flag `valid` is set to true, ending the loop.